# Template Tag in Javascript

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates, django-template-filters

My Django template tags are not working within my javascript. My latest error is: `SyntaxError: expected expression, got '&' var resourceTypes = [&#39;Structural Model&#39;, &#39;X-Ray Diffraction&#39;]`

How can I get this to work? I need to get these Django variables into the js so that I can create a chart (I'm using Google Charts)

index.html

```
<script>
  function drawChart() {

    // Create the data table.
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addColumn('string');
    data.addColumn('number');

    var resourceTypes = {{ "all"|resource_types }}

    {% for x in resourceTypes %}
        data.addRows([
          [x, {{ x|resourceType_count }}],
        ]);
    {% endfor %}

    // Set chart options
    var options = {'title':'Datasets by Type',
                   'width':400,
                   'height':300};

    // Instantiate and draw our chart, passing in some options.
    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
    chart.draw(data, options);
  }

</script>
```

templatetags.py

```
@register.filter(name='resource_types')
def resource_types(data_type):
    resourceTypes = [ str(x.data_type) for x in ResourceType.objects.all() ]
    return resourceTypes

@register.filter(name='resourceType_count')
def resourceType_count(data_type):
    count = Dataset.objects.filter(data_type=ResourceType.objects.get(data_type=data_type)).count()
    return count
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might consider using an assignment tag:

```
from collections import Counter

@register.assignment_tag(takes_context=True)
def get_resource_types(context):
    values = dict(Counter(list(map(str, ResourceType.objects.values_list('data_type', flat=True)))))
    return {'resource_types': values}
```

This will give you a count of each `data_type` string in the values list, such as:

```
{'data type 1': 3, 'data type 2': 10, 'data type 3': 47}
```

which you can then pass to the `.addRows()` function:

```
{% get_resource_types as resource_types %}

data.addRows([
    {% for data_type, count in resource_types.items %}
    ['{{ data_type }}', {{ count }}],
    {% endfor %}
]);
```

That should allow you to do everything in a single database query versus having to query for each one. You could also do that with an aggregate count of each type over the queryset. Depending on how much data we're talking about, I can't say for sure which one would be faster.

Comment: Getting much closer! thank you @brandon That fixed that issue but now the `{% for x in resourceTypes %}` isn't working- any idea why that loop doesn't go?

Comment: What do you mean "isn't working"? Is there an error? is the loop not iterating? Please explain

Comment: There is no error- it's not iterating at all. I added a `console.log(x);` just inside the for loop and that never even prints

Comment: oh, @brandon, just saw your latest edit- I'll give that a try right now as well

Comment: I've added an alternative implementation for you, but on a re-read of your question, I see that you're passing in the data_type to get the count. There's another way to do that. Bear with me and I'll get you an updated implementation.

Comment: Thank you so much- I'm trying to put the `data_type` which is a string and the count, which is an int, into `data.addRows` so I can create a chart

Comment: Added a refactored example. I have to step out for a bit, but will try to help later if possible.

Comment: Excellent! THANK YOU!! I'm getting a new error: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {'resource_types': {u'X-Ray Diffraction': 1, u'Structural Model': 1}}`
I'll see if I can figure it out, and will post back when I end up with

Comment: aah so close again: `SyntaxError: missing ; before statement {'resource_types': {'X-Ray Diffraction': 1, 'Structural Model': 1}}`

Comment: Perhaps at the end of `var resourceTypes = {{ "all"|resource_types }}` ? Which you shouldn't need now, but definitely a JavaScript issue.

Comment: Don't quite follow? I'm using your new implementation only right now...?

Comment: Is the error you're getting on the Javascript side? Or the Python side?

Comment: Javascript- I see it in the console: doesn't seem like the for loop is iterating though, I think the error is happening with `{% get_resource_types %}` just before the for loop

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/80121/discussion-between-brandon-and-plact).